# How to link an external jar file in two java projects

Tags: java, android, libgdx, jfugue

ok guys, I'm trying to import the jfugue android port library into a libdx project, but I don't know how to add the jar files from the core project to the android one, since they don't appear as jar in the add jar option in the android build path project.

[image: libgdx problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jar file you're pointing to is an external jar (you can see it has a full path), so add to the other project using "Add External JARs" button on the "Libraries" tab of the "Java Build Path" page of the project's properties dialog.

Answer (score 0):

> Step-1>Just copy the jar files from Quintas_analizer project and paste
>   them in libs folder of Quintas_analizer-android. Then right click on
>   the jar files in Quintas_analizer-android and add to build path.

or

> Step-1.1 >Another way is that-> right click Quintas_analizer-android
>   ->properties-> Android->Add-> Select the project  Quintas_analizer and add.
>
> If Quintas_analizer not shown then go to  Quintas_analizer ->
>   properties -> Android-> Mark the checkbox ->is a library-> Repeat step
>   1.1